# Using oracle SQL to find duplicates

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm quality checking student test scores and have a couple different tables of interest.

STUDENTTEST has testID, test_date, and studentID.
STUDENTS has student_name, and it has a variable named ID that links to STUDENTTEST's studentid.

I want to find students who have records where both testID and test_date are the same. And I want to be able to have a link to the students table so I can see the names of which students have duplicates.

I hope this makes sense! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can `join` the `students` and `student_tests` table, group by student, test id and test date, and then filter with a `having` clause to retain duplicates only:

```
select s.id, s.student_name, t.test_id, t.test_date, count(*) cnt_duplicates
from students s
inner join student_tests t on t.student_id = s.id
group by s.id, s.student_name, t.test_id, t.test_date
having count(*) > 1
```

Comment: I think I misstated my question... I really have an entire subquery (it's just called query) with student ID in it. It has the students and studenttest tables. How would I join the duplicates to that table?

Comment: @ESIRMITS: it is not possible to answer without seeing the entire existing query (or a simplified version of it if it is too big). I would recommend that you ask a *new* question for that, since answers were posted already for *this* question

Answer (score 0):

You could try uisng a group by and having count(*) >1

```
 select * 
 from STUDENTTEST T
 inner join STUDENTS  S ON s.ID = T.studentid
 group  testID, test_date,  studentID
 having count(*) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm . . . You seem to want students who have taken the same test on the same date more than once.  I am thinking:

```
select *
from students s join
     (select testID, test_date, studentID, count(*) as cnt
      from studenttests st
      group by testID, test_date, studentID
      having count(*) >= 2
     ) st
     using (studentid);
```

This returns one row for each student/test combination that meets your criteria.